# How can a query multiply 2 cell for each row MySQL?

Tags: mysql, multiplication

I want to multiply 2 cells for each row and put the value of that in the last column called Total. Can this be done by a normal query?

Example:

```
Pieces | Price | Total
6      |   4   |  null // should be 24
2      |  10   |  null // should be 10
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT 
    Pieces, Price, 
    Pieces * Price as 'Total' 
FROM myTable
```

Comment: ah, yeah, I don't update, just retrieve with the multiplied price

Comment: is there a way to round it up to 2 decimals ?

Comment: ROUND(Pieces * Price, 2) as `Total`

Answer (score 11):

You can do it with:

```
UPDATE mytable SET Total = Pieces * Price;
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming this should work. This will actually put it in the column in your database

```
UPDATE yourTable yt SET yt.Total = (yt.Pieces * yt.Price)
```

If you want to retrieve the 2 values from the database and put your multiplication in the third column of the result only, then

```
SELECT yt.Pieces, yt.Price, (yt.Pieces * yt.Price) as 'Total' FROM yourTable yt
```

will be your friend

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was self-explanatory when you start your query with `INSERT`. Anyways, if you make an edit I can undo the downvote.

Comment: I did an edit, but if you leave a comment, the writer gets a notification. Now it was just luck I happend to notice the -2. :D

Answer (score -3):

this was my solution:

i was looking for how to display the result not to calculate...

so. in this case. there is no column TOTAL in the database, but there is a total on the webpage...

```
 <td><?php echo $row['amount1'] * $row['amount2'] ?></td>
```

also this was needed first...

```
<?php 
   $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','testbla','adminbla');
mysql_select_db("testa",$conn);

$query1 = "select * from info2";
$get=mysql_query($query1);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get)){
   ?>
```