# How to add expression in column?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql and would like to know how can I add expression in the column like in msaccess?

What data type should I select? Could I use expression directly in the field?

Suppose I have these fields:

```
name: ID type: int(11)
name: one type: int(11)
name: two type: int(11)
name: total: [one]*[two]
```

Comment: Just give code what you want?

Comment: You cannot. You might have a trigger instead or create a view

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a query multiply 2 cell for each row MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693259/how-can-a-query-multiply-2-cell-for-each-row-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have calculated columns. You could however, create a view to simulate this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT id, one, two, one * two AS total
FROM   my_table
```