# select arithmetic operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table materiel that contains four columns(id, nom, quantity, price, amount).

I want to know how to affect the result of column amount.

knowing that : 
amount = price * quantity

I tried with : 
 `SELECT (price * quantity) AS res FROM materiel`

But I would affect the result in the amount column

Comment: Are there four (as mentioned) or five (as listed) columns? Asked differently, is the amount column already part of the DB schema?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693259/how-can-a-query-multiply-2-cell-for-each-row-mysql

Comment: yes column amount is already  part of the table materiel

Comment: Do this Update material set amount=price* quantity

Comment: As you have mentioned, 
> I want to know how to affect the result of column amount. 
knowing that : amount = price * quantity

I understand that you want to update the value of amount as price * quantity. Am I correct in assuming that? If yes, then:

If you want to do a single update then:

    update materiel set amount = price * quantity;